# How to create sequential number column index on table with data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, migration

I have the following table with 10 unique rows, BookingID is a FK containing a random number. The number doesn't need to be in sequence.

```
BookingID, Description
1000       Foo
3000       Bar
1500       Zoo
```

I need to insert an sequential index called ID which goes from 1..x

how do I do that in SQL Server 2005? I was thinking to write a cursor and x=x+1 but maybe there is a better way?

This is the result I want

```
Id, BookingID, Description
1   1000       Foo
2   3000       Bar
3   1500       Zoo
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I need to insert an sequential index called ID". You want to add a new column to the table? If so just insert a new column in the table of `identity(1,1)` - or does the sequence need to be in guaranteed order of  BookingID?

Comment: @Martin do I do that when creating the column in the designer?

Comment: @Makach- Do what? I'm still unclear of the requirement. Is order important?

Comment: @Martin, No I don't think order is important

Comment: @Makach - And when you add new rows you want the sequence to be handled automatically?

Comment: @Martin, no, just once when doing this migration job.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t.bookingid) AS id,
       t.bookingid,
       t.description
  FROM YOUR_TABLE t
```

...will produce:

```
id  bookingid   description
----------------------------
1   1000        Foo
2   3000        Bar
3   1500        Zoo
```

To update the existing `id` column, use:

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT t.id,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t.bookingid) AS rank,
          t.bookingid,
          t.description
     FROM YOUR_TABLE t)
UPDATE cte
   SET id = rank
```

Comment: ponies, yes, it exists and contains null values for each row, but I would like to populate the field with sequential number like you illustrated, but I cannot use identity on the field after the id rows are set.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I wanted. 15000 rows migrated successfully.

Answer (score 0):

BETTER ALTER THAT TABLE ADN ADD A IDENTITY COLUMN LIKE

ALTER TABLE TABLENAME ADD SRNO  IDENTITY(1,1)