# create sequential number column index into table with data

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I wanted to do something like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3983308/how-to-create-sequential-number-column-index-on-table-with-data), so I tried:

```
SELECT 
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t.[Data Saida] ) AS id, 
   t.codigo, t.[Data Saida], t.Entidade, t.DataEnt, 
   t.[GTEntT Nº], t.Estado, t.[GTSaida Nº], t.[Observações1], 
   t.Eequisitante, t.Certificado, T.Resultado, T.Seleccionar, t.[Tipo de Intervenção]
FROM 
   [Movimento ferramentas] t;
```

However I ended up getting something like

> Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t.[Data Saida] )

Is it because `ROW_NUMBER() OVER()` is SQL Server only or am I doing something wrong?

I'm working with MS Access 2010.

Here's a row from that table:

[image: Row of [Movimento ferramentas]]

Comment: As you say, MS Access does not support `row_number()`.  It's SQL Server only.

Comment: @Andomar Any suggestion on how to do it then?

Comment: @Mureinik Far from duplicate. I don't want to add it after each insert, I want to add it into an already existing table with data in every single row of it.

Comment: Insert the rows into another table with an identity column?

Comment: @Andomar adding the column itself is easy, my real issue is filling it. If it was sql server or such I could just use an AUTO_INCREMENT field, but that doesn't exist on MS Access 2010

Comment: If you add an `AutoNumber` field to an existing Access table then Access will populate that field for the existing rows in that table.

Comment: How do I make it *AutoNumber*? Only formats I can see at my disposal are those mentioned [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/access-help/format-property-number-and-currency-data-types-HA001232740.aspx)

Comment: @MicaelFlorêncio If you open the table in Design View you can add the new field and choose `AutoNumber` as the `Data Type`, like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/6K3os.png).

Comment: @GordThompson That's what I was looking for, thanks. While on it, is it possible to order the table before inserting it? Like order it by date to then have the lower numbers of that column match the older records and the higher ones the newer records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add an AutoNumber field to an existing table, simply open the table in Design View, type in the `Field Name` and select "AutoNumber" from the drop-down list for the `Data Type`:

[image: AutoNumber.png]

Access will populate the new field with AutoNumber values for any existing records in the table.

**Edit re: influencing the order in which AutoNumber values are applied to existing records**

As with many other database operations, there is essentially no *guarantee* that Access will use any particular order when assigning the AutoNumber values to existing records. However, if we look at a couple of examples we can see how Access will *likely* do it.

Consider the following sample table named [Events]. The rows were entered in random order and there is no primary key:

```
EventDate   Event         
----------  --------------
2012-06-01  it's June     
2012-10-01  it's October  
2012-09-01  it's September
2012-12-01  it's December 
2012-11-01  it's November 
2012-07-01  it's July     
2012-04-01  it's April    
2012-08-01  it's August   
2012-02-01  it's February 
2012-01-01  it's January  
2012-03-01  it's March    
2012-05-01  it's May
```

Now we'll simply add an AutoNumber field named [ID] using the procedure above. After that has been done

```sql
SELECT * FROM Events ORDER BY ID
```

returns

```
EventDate   Event           ID
----------  --------------  --
2012-06-01  it's June        1
2012-10-01  it's October     2
2012-09-01  it's September   3
2012-12-01  it's December    4
2012-11-01  it's November    5
2012-07-01  it's July        6
2012-04-01  it's April       7
2012-08-01  it's August      8
2012-02-01  it's February    9
2012-01-01  it's January    10
2012-03-01  it's March      11
2012-05-01  it's May        12
```

Now let's revert back to the old copy of the table and see if the existence of a primary key makes a difference. We'll make [Event Date] the primary key, **save the changes to the table**, and *then* add the [ID] AutoNumber field. After that is done, the select statement above gives us

```
EventDate   Event           ID
----------  --------------  --
2012-06-01  it's June        1
2012-10-01  it's October     2
2012-09-01  it's September   3
2012-12-01  it's December    4
2012-11-01  it's November    5
2012-07-01  it's July        6
2012-04-01  it's April       7
2012-08-01  it's August      8
2012-02-01  it's February    9
2012-01-01  it's January    10
2012-03-01  it's March      11
2012-05-01  it's May        12
```

Hmmm, same thing. So it looks like the AutoNumber values get assigned to the table in *natural order* (the order in which the records were added to the table) even if there is a primary key.

Okay, if that's the case then let's use a make-table query to create a new copy of the table in a different order

```sql
SELECT Events.EventDate, Events.Event 
INTO Events2
FROM Events
ORDER BY Events.EventDate;
```

Now let's add the [ID] AutoNumber field to that new table and see what we get:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Events2 ORDER BY ID
```

returns

```
EventDate   Event           ID
----------  --------------  --
2012-01-01  it's January     1
2012-02-01  it's February    2
2012-03-01  it's March       3
2012-04-01  it's April       4
2012-05-01  it's May         5
2012-06-01  it's June        6
2012-07-01  it's July        7
2012-08-01  it's August      8
2012-09-01  it's September   9
2012-10-01  it's October    10
2012-11-01  it's November   11
2012-12-01  it's December   12
```

If that is the order we want then we can just delete the [Events] table and rename [Events2] to [Events].